# Removing T and Z in WFS timestamp o/p field by changing configurations in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, wfs, timestamp

Geoserver is appending T and Z in the values of timestamp columns(postgres DB) in WFS o/p.

```
Current Output:2020-12-11T00:00:00Z
Expected Output:DEC-11-2020 00:00:00
```

Comment: I would create a view that converts time into your preferred format in PostgreSQL and publish that view with GeoServer. The current output is using the ISO 8601 formatting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.

Comment: That is an ISO formatted timestamp including a timezone (Z) GeoServer will always return timestamps like that - how you handle it after you receive it is between you and the client code.

Comment: we are showing as it is at client side because if we handle at client side it causes performance issue multiple timestamp fields at multiple location, so wanted to change in geoserver configuration if possible